# How to make a lowercase variable from jenkins variable

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I have a Jenkins parameterized build which get user input and store into a variable  say `TEST`. User will value for example `MYBRANCH` into `TEST`. 
How can I use a lowercase version of that variable or create another version of that variable with all characters is lowercased.

I try `${TEST.toLowerCase()}` but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Try `${TEST,,}` like it is used for all-lowercasing in [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383352/command-to-convert-an-upper-case-string-to-lower-case)

Comment: Are you really talking about environment variables? Because then you would have to refer to the variable using `env.TEST` in Jenkins Pipelines, don't you? Please show your complete code, from my point of view, `variable.toLowerCase()` should work.

Comment: My build has parameters so user will enter data before doing a build. It's called environment variable ? so user will enter "ABC-1234" into TEST
I use TEST in a bash shell, and as Destination bucket parameter in the Publish Artifact to S3 bucket plugin.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to lower case of existing variable this is solution:

```
env {
   SOME_VAR = "This IS SOME STRING"
}

...
steps{
    script{
        def someVarLower = SOME_VAR.toLowerCase(); 
        SOME_VAR = someVarLower
    }
    sh script: "echo $SOME_VAR"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_tolowercase.htm

In Jenkins:

```
    script {
       def test = TEST.toLowerCase()
       println ${test}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this solve my problem (My context, I'm using Declarative Jenkins Pipeline to create a Docker image, taking some variables from the same pipeline):

```
    pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
       NOMBRE_PIPELINE = "${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}"
       REPO_DES = "URLnombreRepo"
    }
```

lines below:

```
        stage("Build Docker Image") {
            steps {
                script{
                    def nomprePipeline = NOMBRE_PIPELINE.toLowerCase(); 
                    NOMBRE_PIPELINE = nomprePipeline
                    def nombreRepoDes = REPO_DES.toLowerCase();
                    REPO_DES = nombreRepoDes
                }
                sh "docker build -t $REPO_DES/$NOMBRE_PIPELINE:build-${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ."
            }
        }
```

And this works for me. Enjoy!